# Significantly reduced absorption of Ciprofloxacin with concurrently administered Sucralfate is utilized intentionally to treat Colitis?

Tags: absorption-absorb

Many studies proved that concurrent administration of Ciprofloxacin and Sucralfate reduces the maximum concentration of Ciprofloxacin in plasma to approximately 1/10 level.

1. Combined use of ciprofloxacin and sucralfate.
   https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1877263
2. Failure of Prostatitis Treatment Secondary to Probable Ciprofloxacin‐Sucralfate Drug Interaction https://www.researchgate.net/publication/14383813_Failure_of_Prostatitis_Treatment_Secondary_to_Probable_Ciprofloxacin-Sucralfate_Drug_Interaction

Like Rifaximin, the unabsorbed Ciprofloxacin is more effective to act directly inside the colon?

Or because of the chelate of Ciprofloxacin-Aluminum (of Sucralfate), the chelated Ciprofloxacin is no more effective?

I've tried to find long time but no luck.

If somebody helps me with scientific evidences, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've found the chelate complex has similar effect in some article but want to see direct evidence.

Answer (score 3):

Officially, I requested to Bayer who is innovator of Ciprofloxacin and received 1 in-vitro study article.

The author of the in-vitro study concluded that there's possibility as strategic option for intestinal sterilization but clinical study with patients must be confirmed.

Again, this is a in-vitro study but not human clinical study.

In case you're interested with non-profit purpose, you can find the above-mentioned in-vitro study article at the bottom of below linked post or as attached.

I don't mark this as an answer because this is not the direct clinical evidence I've been looking for.

Link-

[Comparison of Antibacterial Activity of Fluoroquinolones with Their Sucralfate-complexes against Clinically-isolated Bacteria_Hitoshi et al_2009](http://cafe.daum.net/greenmission/jUmJ/4)